# How to disable the Last Level Cache only of Intel Ivybridge CPU?

Tags: caching, memory, intel

I know how to disable all of the three levels of cache on Intel IvyBridge CPU. I only need to set the CD bit of CR0 register to 1 for all of CPUs.

However, I want to disable the last level of cache (L3 cache) only on Intel IvyBridget or SandyBridge CPU and keep using the L1 and L2 on chip cache.

The reason why I want to do this experiment is because I want to test the performance of the L3 cache and want to see the effect of not using the L3 cache.

Could any one give me a pointer or some insight on how to achieve that?

Comment: I suspect you would find it in http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/3rd-gen-core-family-mobile-vol-1-datasheet.pdf, or in http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/3rd-gen-core-family-mobile-vol-2-datasheet.pdf, though it is a long read...

Comment: HI @nonsensickle, Thanks for your reply! But I searched in those docs and couldn't find it. I had a look at intel programmer manual before when I wrote the code to disable all cache and trace the cache access ratio. However, I cannot find the manual to disable the LLC. :-(

Comment: Same here, I searched through them without any luck. In general CPU's and micro-controllers have a **datasheet** that describes the details of how they operate. That is what I searched for but the Intel CPU's are rather complex so their documentation is very elaborate. I'll try and find a better document for you but it will be faster if you too look for a **datasheet** with the information you need at the same time.

Comment: Hi @nonsensickle, Thank you very much for your help! Sure! Now I'm worried if Intel really provide such function to disable only the L3 cache. If they don't provide, we can never find it. :(

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If they don't allow a way to disable it, we will never be able to do so. Also, you have to keep in mind that some of this functionality might not be *exposed* by the operating system, meaning that you would have to get around the kernel in order to perform the test... Either way, what you're trying to do probably won't be easy. But there's a certain satisfaction in doing something that is hard :)

Comment: I wrote code to disable the cache on Linux and Xen before. wrmsr needs ring 0 privilege. But I'm not clear if there is some other functionality that are not exposed to OS, even in kernel space?

Comment: I would be very surprised if there was a way to disable the LLC only, the functionality of the CPU relies on it being inclusive.

Comment: Hi @Leeor, but ARM do allow disabling LLC only, which is also inclusive cache. So I'm not sure why Intel does not allow that